# Error message when using the \includepdf command

Tags: pdfpages

I am trying to include a 12 page .pdf file in my masters thesis, but get an error message.

I tried creating a new .tex-file, and the same error-messages showed.

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{AppendixB.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Error messages from Texmaker:

```
Error line 188 !Undefined control sequence.<argument> \nointerlineskip \AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,\ESO@yof...}
Error line 188 !LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}...
Error line 188 !Undefined control sequence.<argument> \ESO@yoffsetl }
Error line 188 !Undefined control sequence.<argument> ... \ESO@HookllBG \@empty }}\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put ... }
Error line 188 !Undefined control sequence.<argument> \ESO@yoffsetl }
```

(The editor wouldn't copy, so i typed the error message manually. There might be some typos)

I appreciate any help in this matter!

Comment: sounds as if you are trying to use a new eso-pic with an old latex. Which tex system do you use?

Comment: I was apparently using an older version. I tried updating, but a new error occured:
The first time I ran the code above, it produced a 13 page document. The first page said "shipout/backgroundshipout/foreground" followed by 12 blank pages (the included pdf is 12 pages)
The seccond time i ran the code above (and every other time) the following error messages was displayed:
Error line 74 !LaTeX Error: File 'calc.sty' not found...
Error line 1 ! = = > Fatal error occured, no output PDF...

Comment: you didn't answer my question ;-(. If calc is missing something is wrong, that is a required file, but better show the complete log-file, I bet your editor is hiding important infos.